# Hide <select> itself if there is no <option> append with it

Tags: jquery, select

I want to hide "select" itself using jquery if there is no "option" append with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can use the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector to find `select` elements with no children:

```
$("select:empty").hide();
```

You may want to consider another answer if you have empty `<optgroup>` element children within the `select` (or any other non-option element children), as `:empty` will consider the `select` to not be empty (it has children, just no `option` children).

Also, as `:empty` looks for elements with no child *nodes* (not just elements), text nodes are included (but note that comment nodes are ignored). That means it would only match `select` elements like this:

```
<select></select> <!--Matches this-->
<select> </select> <!--Doesn't match this-->
```

Comment: I would be careful with this solution because text including space is also considered as a node and not empty. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/kmhhC/. See also http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/.

Comment: @TJ. - Good point, I was just about to add that warning to the answer! I was expecting someone to mention that long before this got to +7!

Comment: if($("select:empty")==true){$(this).hide();} 
doesnot work Why?

Comment: Because `$("select:empty")` is always `true`. It returns a jQuery object. You need to check its `length` property to see if it contains any elements. And what does `this` refer to?

Comment: Thank You James!!! I have just stared jquery and got lots of confusion. Sorry for the this!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() { 
    $("select").each(function() { 
        if ($(this).find("option").length == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: What if it has an empty `optgroup` in it? Or in your case, even an `optgroup` containing `option` elements. Your code will hide it.

Comment: Boom. Fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('select:not(:has(option))').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').each(function () {
    var $select = $(this);
    if ($select.find('option').length === 0) {
        $select.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work correctly if there are more than one `select` tags.

Comment: Removed the downvote, technically it works now. Why not use `filter()`? It would make it also readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't tested it, but this should work:

```
$('select:not(:has(option))').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do.

```
$('select').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).find('option').length){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What if it has an empty `optgroup` in it?